# Prevent duplicate users in Parse

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm writing user based application for android.
I have two options for login:
1. By enter user name and password and email.
2. Via Facebook app.

I want to avoid a status which user will first login with his Facebook user and then later he will create new user with his email registered at Facebook or viceversa.
I want to let the option to a user who initially registered by Facebook to login again by using user name and password.

Is there any way to ensure it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could have suggested you to get the user Email ID & password form Facebook when he login via Facebook but you can't get the password anyhow so that won't work.

What you can do is get the Facebook Email ID and save it in SharedPreferences. Then when the user tries to login using Email ID then just populate the Email field with the saved Email and ask the user to enter the password. Basically you'll ask him to register. (Make a Parse account using that very Email Id he).

> If the user will uninstall the application and later install a new
>   copy of the application, then he will succeed to create another user
>   with his email.

To tackle this you can create the Parse account using his Facebook ID and set a default password (It can be anything, !@12345 or simply his  Email ID). Then after creating his Parse account you can simply send him a Mail Alert using Parse Mailing System. That way his both account will be created when he login using Facebook.

**Updated Answer:**

Why don't you simply go through Parse Android Docs which explains how to link Facebook with Parse.com.

Basic example for combining both is as following:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
    if (user == null) {
      Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
    } else if (user.isNew()) {
      Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
    } else {
      Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
    }
  }
});
```

you can go through detailed version [here](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
I think that use the shared preferences is a little bit problematic. if the user will uninstall the application and later install a new copy of  the application, then he will succeed to create another user with his email.
I'm looking for a solution that'll create the Parse user with his email from the first place. Is there any way to do that? 
Maybe i can modify the Parse callback?

Comment: not yet. i'm currently leaving the Facebook login option. If i'll decide to use it later i'll try your advice. Thanks :)

Comment: It's not that complicated. In new SDK that you might be using, they have added this feature. 5 lines of code and you're good to go. Just use `ParseFacebookUtils.logIn`.